# How can I handle image memory in a WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a very image intensive application in WPF. I'm managing memory the best way possible, but the images are pushing me way over budget. They just simply stop rendering at a certain point and then the application crashes. I'm binding an image control's source to a given path.

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImagePath, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Is there a better way to handle this? Maybe I can turn off the caching? I know the problem is with the images because when I stop displaying them the problem goes away.

Comment: What kind of images are you using? How many? Is ImagePath a path to an image file? Have you tried Mode=OneTime?

Comment: I've not tried OneTime. But an image control shouldn't update that binding unless the source changes and it doesn't.

Comment: Yes its just troubleshooting. Narrowing down the possible causes.

Comment: You need to create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Although solving this probably requires using a memory profiler.

Comment: @MobyDisk, I am not looking for a diagnosis. I know what is wrong. I'm looking for a way of solving an issue that I already understand. Besides being unnecessary, an MCVE would be way to long to post.

Comment: Is the problem that 1) there are too many simultaneous images, or that 2) it is keeping images in memory after they are no longer referenced?  If it is (1) then you might be running out of memory and just be stuck.  If it is (2) then the GC should know to collect the image objects before it crashes.  Perhaps something isn't adding appropriate memory pressure?  Also, I'm unclear what "managing memory the best way possible" means.

Comment: The image control is doing some sort of magic that is keeping the image in memory even after the control is unloaded. Also, how would I provide an MCVE with the 250 images that go along with it? The problem is the throughput of images. The GC is not getting rid of them fast enough. I'm wanting to release the memory as soon as the image is no longer being used (e.g., the user goes to another page).

Answer (score 0):

I think that my problem was that images were being unnecessarily recreated. I don't know how. I don't know why. When I created my own caching service and used `BitmapImage` instead of a path, the memory problem went away. I could even see this being wrapped into a converter that takes a path and produces a cached `BitmapImage`. This is not ideal. It only gets rid of the duplicates. I still have to play with the expiration, but I'm happy with this as a solution.

```
public class ImageCachingSystem : IImageCachingSystem
{
    private readonly DispatcherTimer _timer = new DispatcherTimer();

    private readonly object l_cachesByName = new object();
    private readonly Dictionary<String, ImageCache> _cachesByName = new Dictionary<String, ImageCache>();

    public ImageCachingSystem()
    {
        _timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
        _timer.Tick += OnTick;
        _timer.Start();
    }

    public BitmapImage GetImage(String a_path)
    {
        return GetImage(new Uri(a_path));
    }

    public BitmapImage GetImage(Uri a_url)
    {
        lock (l_cachesByName)
        {
            var path = a_url.ToString().ToLower();

            if (_cachesByName.ContainsKey(path))
            {
                return _cachesByName[path].Image;
            }
            else
            {
                var image = new BitmapImage(a_url);
                image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
                image.Freeze();

                _cachesByName[path] = new ImageCache
                {
                    Expiration = DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    Path = path,
                    Image = image,
                };

                return image;
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lock (l_cachesByName)
        {
            var expired = _cachesByName.Where(i => i.Value.Expiration < DateTime.Now).Select(i => i.Key);

            foreach (var key in expired.ToArray())
                _cachesByName.Remove(key);
        }
    }


    class ImageCache
    {
        public String Path { get; set; }
        public DateTime Expiration { get; set; }
        public BitmapImage Image { get; set; }
    }
}
```